# Why is Heroku not showing my custom header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, header, heroku

I have this code:

```
response.headers["X-ERROR-MESSAGE"] = "A message"
render :text => "Some text", :status => 400
```

On my local machine I can get the response headers successfully but when I try it on Heroku, they don't show up. What could be the problem? Is Heroku filtering out my header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. I just asked Heroku support and they said that Heroku makes those headers camel-case. So `X-ERROR-MESSAGE` will show up as `X-Error-Message`.